# How to use 'where in' clause using 'Bracket' in typeorm?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

Im creating an SQL query using typeOrm's queryBuilder. I am trying to use `Bracket` and `where in` clause. However, I am getting this error.

```js
const users = [
  {
    name: 'user1',
    age: 20,
    nickname: 'u1'
  },
  {
    name: 'user2',
    age: 24,
    nickname: 'u2'
  },
  {
    name: 'user3',
    age: 42,
    nickname: 'u3'
  }
];
const queryBuilder = this.queryBuilder();

queryBuilder.where(
  new Brackets((qb) => {
    qb.orWhere('user.nickname IN (:...nicknames)', { nicknames: users.map((user) => user.nickname) });
    qb.orWhere(...);
  })
);

...

return queryBuilder.getMany();
```

then, return error

```json
TypeError. value.map is not a function
```

How do I implement this correctly?

Comment: Can you please show the entire stack trace?

Answer (score -1):

This error is happening because you're trying to use the ".map()" function on a variable that isn't an array. In this case, you're trying to use ".map()" on the "users" variable, which is actually an array of objects. To fix this error, you need to map over the "nickname" property of each object in the "users" array, rather than trying to map over the entire array.
You can try extracting just the nicknames from the objects in the users array using the map function, like this:

```
const nicknames = users.map((user) => user.nickname);
```

Then, you can pass nicknames to your where function

```
queryBuilder.where(
  new Brackets((qb) => {
    qb.orWhere('user.nickname IN (:...nicknames)', { nicknames });
    qb.orWhere(...);
  })
);
```